# How to define decimal places?

Tags: r

I am using r studio to do some quick calculation since I didn't have a calculator at hand, and this is the results(posted below). It seems R studio automatically rounded the decimal place. Is there a way to change it?(My homework is machine graded, which means I am not allowed to round the results)!
[image]

Comment: Play around with `options(digits = )`

Comment: You can also simply use `print` to only print out a single instance, e.g. `print(500000*(1+0.05)^10, digits = 22)`.

Comment: It's not RStudio, but R. And it is rounded for display purpose.

Comment: Thanks, guys.I am new here. Should I leave the post as it is since I got the answer?